# There are no items in TeamProject in Reporting site

Tags: tfs, reporting

When I opened the Report site (in created Team Project), I am faced with the "There are no items in **TeamProject**. Click Help for more information about this page"

Report site: team Explorer>Right-click on Reports in team explorer and select **show Report site**, then open the Report site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. check tfs server health with "Best Practices Analyzer" tool
2. call the command line option to install the new templates

   > tfpt addprojectreports /collection:%serverName\CollectionName% /teamp
   >   roject:%TeamProjectName% /processtemplate:"MSF for Agile Software
   >   Development v5.0" /force

to add all of the Reports for a Process Template to TFS

Answer (score 1):

I assume you use TFS 2010. When you go into the TFS Admin Console (you can find it on the TFS server), open the Team Project Collections Node. You have there the [Reports Folder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee712737.aspx). Please check whether it is correctly configured.

Comment: settings are correct in "Reports Folder", because reporting is done correctly in new TeamProjects